# Need Apex REST Endpoint to Return HTML Page

Tags: apexrest

I'm trying to use Dotmailer's [external dynamic content](https://support.dotmailer.com/hc/en-gb/articles/212212948-Working-with-external-dynamic-content) to render dynamic content for an email from sfdc data

I initally almost had this working using a visualforce page exposed in a force.com site, but the vf page includes javascript in the headers, that I was unable to remove, which caused rendering issues in a small number of cases.

Dotmailer support indicates that the expected response is a html page. So I'm trying to use an apex REST endpoint to return a HTML page.  I've [set one up here](https://dev-ashoka.cs71.force.com/dyncon/services/apexrest/Applications), which is set to return a string as a response.  The string is not rendered in the email, as the page is returning xml.

I'm probably missing something basic as my background knowledge on how http requests work is limited, but any suggestions on how to address this are appreciated.  The rather elementary code for my endpoint is below:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Applications/*') 
global with sharing class applicationEndpoint {    

    @HttpGet
    global static string GetTitle() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        res.addHeader('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');        
        String resp = 'session title';
        return resp;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Without Rest

I don't think you need a rest service. If you send a request to a normal HTML page you get the content on the page. If you add query parameters to your URL you can communicate with a controller on the page (in this case apex) to dynamically generate your content.

If you're having issues with the scrips, remove or modify them or clone the page and then remove them from the new page.

### With Rest

If you absolutely can't do that and have to do it via rest I think you're on the right track.

I don't think you're actually getting XML. I think your mistake is that you're viewing it in a browser. When I made a request in postman all the response contained was

> "session title"

When viewed in Chrome, the content of the page is wrapped inside of XML, probably because it doesn't know what to do with a plain string.

**If you update your code to deliver a valid HTML string you might get a different result.** Something like `<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World!</h1><hr/><p>WE DID IT!!</p></body></html>`

### Update

Instead of returning a string, return a valid rest response. Try:

```
global static RestResponse GetTitle() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    res.addHeader('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    res.setBody('<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World!</h1><hr/><p>WE DID IT!!</p></body></html>');
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: thanks unfortunately there is no way to remove the scripts.  they are included on any visualforce page even w/ show header +++ set to off/false.  if you view the source of the page in the browser you can see it starts with xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8 - and i think that is the piece i need to change.  but i'm not reallys ure how.  i'll try including the full html string and see.

Comment: Finish reading my answer. I explained to you why it shows as XML and what you need to do.

Comment: thanks i will try to see how it resolves in dotmailer again when presenting the string w the html tags.

Comment: I see that you updated it and in my postman test the page is wrapped in quotes which prevent it from being rendered correctly

Comment: After checking postman it shows the content type as json still, it appears to not be honoring your content type. I updated my answer with something else for you to try

Comment: it actually came through fine by just including the html tags.  i had missed a final confirmation step in dotmailer in my initial test, so my orig approach does come through it is wrapped in quotes (for whatever reason).  I'm going to try the valid rest response approach as well, but will give you best answer now as i think one or the other is about all i need.

Comment: Returning a valid rest response w the HTML inside ended up working best.

Comment: @gNerb: your answer did not work for me. Salesforce says that RestResponse is not a valid ReturnType for HTTPGet.

"HttpGet methods do not support return type of System.RestResponse (4:32)"
gorav how did you manage to return valid html? can you please share your code?

Comment: @TheShadow Please ask a new question with specific code samples of what you have tried along side specific error messages.

Comment: @gNerb seems not be worth a question because of documentation: RestResponse is not allowed as ReturnType: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm

Therefor it cannot be made by REST Endpoint AND your answer regarding  "Without Rest" is applicable for my problem.

Comment: @gNerb I posted our Problem here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279198/access-third-party-ressource-using-a-link feel free to comment! :-)